# Golang Firebase admin SDK

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore, google-admin-sdk

Assuming a Firebase Datastore Db that is...

```
Collection("Collection1").
Document("documentX").
Collection("CollectionA").
field("FieldB")
```

In Golang, using firebase admin SDK... What would the code be to get value of FieldB in GoLang?
this is what I've tried...

```
// dsnapp, err :=     client.Collection("Collection1/documentX").Get(ctx)
// dsnapp, err := client.Collection("Collection1").Document("documentX").Collection["CollectionA"].Get(ctx)

dsnapp2, err := client.Collection("Collection1").Doc("documentX").Get(ctx)
m = dsnapp2.Data()
fmt.Printf("222  Document data: %#v\n", m["CollectionA"]["FieldB")
```

and assorted other techniques...   any suggestions?

Comment: A field can't exist directly within a collection.  A collection or subcollection can only contain documents, and documents contain fields.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Doug.

Comment: How about retrieving the entire doc, unmarshal it and then get the value from the struct ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all like @Doug Stevenson said a collection only contains documents. So know we can use this structure as a foundation for our request.

```
Collection (CollectionA) -> Document (documentX) -> Collection (CollectionB) -> Document (documentY) -> Field (FieldB)
```

You should consider to read a little within the go documentation of the firebase admin sdk.
https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore

There you can see that we can chain our requests as needed. So your query would look like this:

```golang
dsnapp2, err := client.Collection("Collection1").Doc("documentX").Collection("Collection1").Document("documentY").Get(ctx)
m := dsnapp2.Data() // it is important to use the := operator if you havn't initialized the variable yet

fmt.Printf("222  Document data: %#v\n", m["FieldB")
```

But if you need more than one field you should consider to unmarshal your result, like the first document (documentX), to an struct. From there you are also able to get your needed fields.